# How can I get a value from an attribute inside a tag as a int

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a soup object like:

```
class="js-product-discount-item product-discount__item ">
                                            <p class="product-discount__price js-product-discount-price">
                                                <span class="price">3 033 <span class="currency w500">₽<span class="currency_seo">руб.</span></span></span>                                            </p>
```

I did

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
price_2 = soup.find(class_='price-discount-value').find(class_='price').text.strip()
x = 2
```

Result :

```
3 033 ₽руб.
```

I'd like to make:

```
price_3 = price_2/x
```

I have : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You are extracting a `string` with `.text` but to use the `/` operand it should be an `int`

#### How to fix?

First at all, clean your `string` from non digit characters:

```
...find(class_='price').text.split('₽')[0].replace(' ','')
```

For calculating convert it  with `int()` to an integer:

```
int(price_2)/x
```

#### Example

**Note** Changed the `find()` for these example, cause your question do not provide an correct `html`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p class="product-discount__price js-product-discount-price">
<span class="price">3 033 <span class="currency w500">₽<span class="currency_seo">руб.</span></span></span>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
price_2 = soup.find(class_='product-discount__price').find(class_='price').text.split('₽')[0].replace(' ','')
x = 2
price_3 = int(price_2)/x
print(price_3)
```

#### Output

```
1516.5
```

Comment: Hi. i have error. (  price_3 = int(price_2)/2
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3\xa0033\xa0'

Comment: Looks like you didn't follow rule number 1, clean up your string - Please take a closer look to the answer and try again. Added the `...find()` in front, to point in right direction.

Comment: Sorry, wher can addet ... find() ?